# Include Facebook Page Reviews without using Facebook App

Tags: php, html, facebook, review

I am setting up a site which allows businesses to list themselves. The site will display reviews from the site as well as from their Facebook and Google pages. I've included reviews from Google easily but Facebook makes this a challenge.

I am looking at alternative ways to do this without the App. For example, using a page link such as:

[https://www.facebook.com/pg/whiteroomtattoo/reviews/](https://www.facebook.com/pg/blecsw/reviews/)

Will bring up the page, where I can right click, view source and see some reviews in the HTML code. Is there a way I can then take this information and manage it in PHP?

I have tried something like the following:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.facebook.com/pg/blecsw/reviews');
$data = $dom->getElementById("banner");
print_r($dom->saveHTML());
```

Although this just outputs the page source in to the website. I've also looked in to cURL options and such but from what I can see there isn't any specific way to achieve this easily? Any help would be greatly appreciated. My aim is to just load the HTML Source and add each review to an array so I can do a `foreach` loop. The HTML Source Code for each review shows similar to this:

```
<div><div class="h_6xnmr0tpn n_6xnmqza7u clearfix"><div class="clearfix j_6xnmr0uus"><a target="" class="_5pb8 y_6xnmqza7_ _8o _8s lfloat _ohe" title="Matthew Mitchell Arkison" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;m&quot;&#125;" href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001579405452&amp;fref=nf&amp;__tn__=%2Cdm-R-R&amp;eid=ARB4JWKt2LO925xJ2gHkVsVTwSv6doss3p27KL0TlZ7fUtG534yQFM61A2K-vqOd9x3uymcfaZ9QJEjL" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100001579405452&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22__tn__%22%3A%22%2Cdm-R-R%22%2C%22eid%22%3A%22ARB4JWKt2LO925xJ2gHkVsVTwSv6doss3p27KL0TlZ7fUtG534yQFM61A2K-vqOd9x3uymcfaZ9QJEjL%22%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1"><div class="_38vo"><noscript id="u_0_1k"></noscript><div><img class="_s0 _4ooo _5xib _5sq7 _44ma _rw img" src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/31064295_1748325608563402_8288956041409601542_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&amp;_nc_oc=AQk0ihDQDM_0kqwbcFHGv56pM4w0fVDrsJbCHIm2ZOA1vdVxfMPFeeOTIjiXimF7riJ5r52StfktWI84e7ycFxGU&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-lhr3-1.xx&amp;oh=65fd0256e3847be697162ec4ab283373&amp;oe=5DBA7D83" alt="" aria-label="Matthew Mitchell Arkison" role="img" /></div></div></a><div class="clearfix _42ef"><div class="rfloat _ohf"></div><div class="b_6xnmr0uuz"><div><div class="_6a _5u5j"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:40px"></div><div class="_6a _5u5j _6b"><h5 class="_7tae _14f3 _14f5 _5pbw _5vra" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;C&quot;&#125;"><span class="fwn fcg"><span class="fcg"><span class="fwb"><a class="profileLink" title="Matthew Mitchell Arkison" href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001579405452&amp;__tn__=%2CdlC-R-R&amp;eid=ARDuKp1CF3iigPFxMTfYpus8QzAP-f-xUQf297nyaQGqdKBJadKMt6aI4MBWuXT73-dVtet8AUxfyG1h&amp;hc_ref=ARRYTZRfCtc78auyrOvnd0Vxo6GLw3KQWyUx2waQu94QTqKN5Pk4s6Q4FVJ6YQ5_Yzs" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;l&quot;&#125;" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100001579405452&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22__tn__%22%3A%22%2CdlC-R-R%22%2C%22eid%22%3A%22ARDuKp1CF3iigPFxMTfYpus8QzAP-f-xUQf297nyaQGqdKBJadKMt6aI4MBWuXT73-dVtet8AUxfyG1h%22%2C%22hc_ref%22%3A%22ARRYTZRfCtc78auyrOvnd0Vxo6GLw3KQWyUx2waQu94QTqKN5Pk4s6Q4FVJ6YQ5_Yzs%22%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1" data-hovercard-referer="ARRYTZRfCtc78auyrOvnd0Vxo6GLw3KQWyUx2waQu94QTqKN5Pk4s6Q4FVJ6YQ5_Yzs">Matthew Mitchell Arkison</a></span> <i class="_51mq img sp_dlUIe9LrYFr sx_9a69a6"></i> recommends <a class="profileLink" href="https://www.facebook.com/blecsw/?__tn__=%2CdkC-R-R&amp;eid=ARAbWWd4dd55tjedmWiJ7zbsOqu_c25zB7PflTn3MP5318lnxUMrjVjCcciojGL4l8Kx-_MiLZa8LM2G&amp;hc_ref=ARRYTZRfCtc78auyrOvnd0Vxo6GLw3KQWyUx2waQu94QTqKN5Pk4s6Q4FVJ6YQ5_Yzs&amp;fref=tag" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;k&quot;&#125;" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=1988949078000580&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22__tn__%22%3A%22%2CdkC-R-R%22%2C%22eid%22%3A%22ARAbWWd4dd55tjedmWiJ7zbsOqu_c25zB7PflTn3MP5318lnxUMrjVjCcciojGL4l8Kx-_MiLZa8LM2G%22%2C%22hc_ref%22%3A%22ARRYTZRfCtc78auyrOvnd0Vxo6GLw3KQWyUx2waQu94QTqKN5Pk4s6Q4FVJ6YQ5_Yzs%22%2C%22fref%22%3A%22tag%22%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1" data-hovercard-referer="ARRYTZRfCtc78auyrOvnd0Vxo6GLw3KQWyUx2waQu94QTqKN5Pk4s6Q4FVJ6YQ5_Yzs">BLEC</a>.</span></span></h5><div class="_5pcp _5lel _2jyu _232_" id="feed_subtitle_2208536022542356:67:0" data-testid="story-subtitle"><span class="n_6xnmr2axm"><span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq" href="/permalink.php?story_fbid=2208536022542356&amp;id=100001579405452" target=""><abbr title="02/03/2019, 20:16" data-utime="1551557764" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz"><span class="timestampContent">2 March</span></abbr></a></span></span><span class="_6spk" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"> · </span><div class="_6a _29ee _4f-9 _43_1" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Shared with: Public" role="img" aria-label="Shared with: Public"><span><i class="_1lbg img sp_xkmPxZzisR6 sx_c88796"></i></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div data-testid="post_message" class="_5pbx userContent _3576" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;&#125;"><p>great company sorted my office  out in fast time and at a very good price</p></div><div class="_3x-2" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;H&quot;&#125;"><div data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;H&quot;&#125;"><div class="mtm"></div></div></div><div></div></div></div><div><form rel="async" class="commentable_item" method="post" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;]&quot;&#125;" action="/ajax/ufi/modify.php" onsubmit="" id="u_0_1j"><input type="hidden" name="jazoest" value="22186" autocomplete="off" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="AQGbwssOWOKR:AQGpeH4QYxqi" autocomplete="off" /><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="ft_ent_identifier" value="2208536022542356" /><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="data_only_response" value="1" /><div class="_sa_ _gsd _fgm _5vsi _192z _1sz4 _1i6z"><div class="_37uu"></div></div><div class="uiUfi UFIContainer _3-a6 _4eno _1blz _69ad _65_9 _5pc9 _5vsj _5v9k" id="u_0_1i"></div></form></div></div></div></div>
```

If there is any other way to do this that I am unaware of would be great to know?

Comment: Scraping Facebook like this will eventually get your IP banned. Creating a Facebook app takes a couple of minutes - just do it. Implementation of a full OAuth flow takes a bit longer, if you need all that, but it's fairly straightforward.

Comment: @ceejayoz there doesn't seem to be a specific option on the Facebook app to do this though, it allows you to include your own reviews but I'm concerned this won't allow other pages reviews to be added?

Comment: although, you need to use page tokens to get reviews of facebook pages, so it will be more than just a couple of minutes, scraping is not allowed as ceejayoz commented, so don´t do it. of course you can only get reviews of pages you manage - or your customers, who would authorize your app to request a page token for their page.

Comment: @Snappysites You'd use OAuth to have your users authenticate. They'd connect their pages to your application, and you'd use the resulting tokens to get their reviews.

Comment: If you can't scrape it, you can always use third-party tools eg: http://www.brightlocal.com, https://www.reviewsmaker.com/api/demo/facebook/, and a few out there if you Google it. Unless you got your app properly setup with native implementation by the book you'll find yourself having a hard time to accomplish what you need. You can use a third-party service in the interim while your app gets published possibly;